# Modbus library in c# to generate packets and convert the response

Tags: c#, modbus

Is any Modbus library available to generate the Ascii packet from slaveAdress, StartingRegister and numberofRegister like

string AsciiPacket = await GeneratePacket(slaveAdress, StartingRegister, numberofRegister);

or

byte[] AsciiBytes = await GeneratePacket(slaveAdress, StartingRegister, numberofRegister);

and once received the response then need to convert back into human-readable format like,

string humanReadableFormat = await ConvertResponse(bytes of array);

Please suggest if any NuGet package is available for this...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Net.Sockets
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets?view=net-5.0

```
        Socket socketDevice;

        socketDevice = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        ipEndPort = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("IPAddress"), intPort);

        socketDevice.Connect(ipEndPort);

        byte[] sendData=//byte array;
        byte[] receivedData= new byte[1024];

        socketDevice.Send(sendData);
        socketDevice.Receive(receivedData);

        var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(receivedData);
```

or you can use EasyModbus http://easymodbustcp.net/en/

```
ModbusClient modBusDevice;
modBusDevice = new ModbusClient("IPAddress", int(Port));
modBusDevice.Connect();

bool[] data = new bool[1024];

data = modBusDevice.ReadDiscreteInputs(int(First discrete input to read), int( Number of discrete Inputs to read));
```

NET: Modbus-TCP  Client Simple Read and Write operations

```
        ModbusClient modbusClient = new ModbusClient("190.201.100.100", 502);    //Ip-Address and Port of Modbus-TCP-Server
        modbusClient.Connect();                                                    //Connect to Server
        modbusClient.WriteMultipleCoils(4, new bool[] {true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true});    //Write Coils starting with Address 5
        bool[] readCoils = modbusClient.ReadCoils(9,10);                        //Read 10 Coils from Server, starting with address 10
        int[] readHoldingRegisters = modbusClient.ReadHoldingRegisters(0,10);    //Read 10 Holding Registers from Server, starting with Address 1

        // Console Output
        for (int i = 0; i < readCoils.Length; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("Value of Coil " + (9 + i + 1) + " " + readCoils[i].ToString());
                    
        for (int i = 0; i < readHoldingRegisters.Length; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("Value of HoldingRegister " + (i + 1) + " "+ readHoldingRegisters[i].ToString());            
        modbusClient.Disconnect();                                                //Disconnect from Server
        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Comment: communicating over BLE, so only need a library to create request frame and once I got response over BLE, convert that Response into human readable format.